# android: creating gui at runtime by downloading and parsing the layout.xml

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create the GUI in an android app during runtime.
For e.g. I have two xmls 
1. layout1.xml available at url (http://localhost/layout1.xml) 
2. layout2.xml available at url (http://localhost/layout2.xml)

When the android app is launched, user inputs one of the above url, then say clicks "OK".
The app will download the corresponding xml. (let us skip how it downloads, i have the code for this), and then the next screen that comes up should have the GUI generated from the xml that it downloaded.
The xml conforms to same guidelines that are used if i would have created these xml during development of the apk and placed them under "res/layout". 
Is this possible to achieve ?

Comment: Only if you write your own parser and use it to create your own `View` objects. The built-in layout inflation logic only works on layout resources, the ones compiled into your app.

Comment: In that case, is there a xsd available that describes the layout.xml structure, with which i can auto-generate sources (using jaxb), and then using these sources and unmarshaller i unmarshall the downloaded xmls, and then create the View objects ?

Comment: "In that case, is there a xsd available that describes the layout.xml structure" -- not that I am aware of. AFAIK, it is not possible, as the element names are not known ahead of time. "with which i can auto-generate sources (using jaxb)" -- Android does not support JAXB.